# Problems with temperature and Mac fan

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

My Mac is showing lots of errors and running weirdly. The battery only lasts for a short time, there is a fan noise when I use it and I feel the temperature is high.

In the report it says the following:

> *** Panic Report ***
>   panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801db6ac55): "zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone semaphores, likely due to memory leak in zone ipc ports (3957835360 total bytes, 24736458 elements allocated)"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.50.9/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2521

Comment: What apps are you running -= this looks like a bug in one of them - When working temperature increases and fan turns on so I would just worry about the panic

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting your SMC (System Management Controller)? 
I had a similar problem with an old MacBook Pro 15" that I solved with this:

You might check [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) where Apple support indicates what you need to check before resetting your SMC.

Steps are:

**Reset the SMC on Mac notebook computers**

**If the battery is nonremovable:**

- Shut down your Mac.
- Unplug the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter from your computer.
- Using the built-in keyboard, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds.
  If you have a 2016 MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power button.
- Release all keys.
- Reconnect the power adapter.
- Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

**Reset the SMC on Mac desktop computers**

**Follow these steps for iMac, Mac mini, Mac Pro, and Xserve.**

- Shut down your Mac.
- Unplug the power cord.
- Wait 15 seconds.
- Plug the power cord back in.
- Wait five seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.

Then I would recommend using tools like **SMC Fan Control** or **iStat Menus** to control your fans and check memory and power usage.

Sorry if I don't answer your question in Spanish (I'm Latin American), but I think that we can't write answers in anything but English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try what you suggest and I'll tell you how it was.